# How to solve this problem except calculate it directly

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \int_0^\infty 1-\left(1-e^{-2w}\right)^8 dw $$
I really don't know how to solve this problem except calculate it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=1-e^{-2w}$ to get

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{1} \ \dfrac{1-u^{8}}{1-u} du $$

and use the fact that

$$\dfrac{1-x^n}{1-x} = x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\cdots + x + 1$$

Comment: oh!thank you!let me use this method to have a try

Comment: the answer I got is 761/560. Thank you!

Comment: That is correct